# Functional "upsert" on nested array in nested array of objects: use optics somehow?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, traversal, lenses

Suppose I have the following types

```js
interface State {
  parents: Parent[]
}
interface Parent {
  uniqueName: string
  children: Child[]
  // other props
}
interface Child { 
  uniqueName: string 
  parentName: string
  // other props
}

declare const upsert: (c:Child) => Parent[] => Parent[]
```

I want to write the last function, `upsert`. Is there a canonical way of doing this functionally, where given a child (might be a new child or a modified child, the function will look through each parent, and update a matching child (match by `uniqueName`) or insert the input child if no matching child is found?

The `update` part is simple optics:

```js
const update = child => 
  parentTraversal
  .filter(matchesNameOf(child.parent))
  .composeLens(_children)
  .composeTraversal(childTraversal)
  .filter(matchesNameOf(child))
  .set(child)(state.parents)
```

The insert part is a combination:

```js
const insert = child => 
  parentTraversal
  .filter(matchesNameOf(child.parent))
  .composeLens(_children)
  .modify(cs => snoc(cs, child))(state.parents)
```

If I know ahead of time whether I'm updating or inserting, then I could just do

```js
if(isNew) insert(child)(state)
else update(child)(state)
```

But is there a completely functional way to combine these, especially if you do not know ahead of time whether it's an update or insert?

**Edit** At the request of a commenter, I'll specify:

```js
declare const _children: Lens<Parent,Child[]>
declare const parentTraversal: Traversal<Parent>
declare const childTraversal: Traversal<Child>
declare const matchesNameOf: <A extends {name:string}>(a:A) => (b:A) => boolean
```

and then `filter`, `composeTraversal`, `composeLens`, `set`, and `modify` are the standard optics functions belonging to lenses and traversals

Comment: Please provide all your code. Where are the definitions of `parentTraversal`, `childTraversal`, `matchesNameOf`, `_children`, `composeLens`, `composeTraversal`, `set`, `modify`, etc? Please provide a [minimal workable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Oh whoops, I didn't specify I'm using `fp-ts`. Half of what you're asking about are built in functions for that library!

Comment: But I'm not asking for my code to be corrected, so a minimal reproducible example seems unnecessary. I'm asking for how to do something and providing code merely to show what I've tried. It's akin to me asking if there's a monad that represents nullability/optionality, and how you don't need a minimal reproducible example to answer ("yes, the Maybe monad")

My code is rock solid and works. But I'm asking if there's a canonical way to do an upsert using optics. (Apparently the answer might be related to an **achromatic lens**, which can create as well as update)